# Do top cabinets have to remain as a whole unit or can select cabinets be removed without sacrificing strength?

Tags: cabinets

Like in these pics, is it possible to only remove single cabinets?

[image]

Comment: Protip: _Save those_. They're a valuable component in a kitchen when it comes to resale value.

Comment: Those two are pretty clearly separate units, the 4 you are leaving are *most likely* a pair of 2-door cabinets conjoined, but could be a single 4-door or four 1-door units conjoined.

Comment: You'll need to do some painting...hopefully you still have some of the paint, and it's not too old, or you're gonna be repainting the whole kitchen.

Comment: Why are you removing so much useful storage from your kitchen?

Answer (score 11):

The cabinets you have Xed, are no doubt hung as a single unit. Look inside near the top back of the cabinets you want to remain.  There should be screws holding that set of cabinets to the wall.  if they are there you are good to remove the others on the sides.

The end cabinets and the middle cabinets may have screws connecting them together.  You will have to look for those and remove them as well. There may be screws from the end cabs into the middles or middle to end or even both.

Good luck

Comment: Also if you are just removing these and not replacing with anything, you may need decorative end panels and/or crown molding on the newly exposed left and right sides of the cabinets.  You can probably re-use parts of the ones you remove, so try not to damage them in the process.

Comment: The crown molding on the corner cabinet will be mitered to match the angle with the molding on the front, so while it may be reusable on the new perpendicular end, it will need to be cut, and won't be reusable if the OP puts the cabinets back up for home sale (at that point it might be best to just remove the crown entirely).

Answer (score 7):

Those cabinets can be removed like @RMDman has stated in his answer. Some screws might even be under the cabinets so check all over the cabinets for screw locations. Also, remove the doors before removing any screws and protect the area below them because they'll be heavy and can drop fast. If you can prop up the cabinets before removing the screws, do so.

Comment: If any shelves are removable, take them out as well...